# Template match with OpenXML

Tags: xslt, xpath, openxml

This is super straightforward stuff, it seems to me, but I cannot figure out how to select a node in the following format using XPath:

```
<w:p>
            <w:pPr />
            <w:customXml w:uri="DxDitaOXmlPub" w:element="msgnum">
              <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                  <w:rStyle w:val="Dxmsgnum" />
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>Consult your compliance officer.</w:t>
              </w:r>
            </w:customXml>
          </w:p>
```

I have tried numerous variations on the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" 
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">

<!-- Identity Transform -->

<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() "/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:p[descendant::w:rPr/w:rStyle/@w:val='msgnum']">

    <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="ActionRequired" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:customXml w:uri="DxDitaOXmlPub" w:element="Dxmsgnum">
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rStyle w:val="Dxmsgnum" />
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>
                    <xsl:value-of select="descendant::w:t"/>
                </w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:customXml>
    </w:p>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired result is really nothing fancy, just modifying the `w:pPr` element to include a non-empty child `w:pStyle`:

```
 <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="ActionRequired" />
            </w:pPr>
            <w:customXml w:uri="DxDitaOXmlPub" w:element="Dxmsgnum">
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="Dxmsgnum" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>
                        Consult your compliance officer.
                    </w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:customXml>
        </w:p>
```

I don't see any reason why the stylesheet doesn't do what I want as-is, but I am not termendously familiar with the OpenXML format, so maybe there's something funky I'm not aware of?

EDIT: I have also tried matching on the `@w:element` as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[child::w:customXml/@w:element='msgnum']">

        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="ActionRequired" />
            </w:pPr>
            <w:customXml w:uri="DxDitaOXmlPub" w:element="msgnum">
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:rStyle w:val="Dxmsgnum" />
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>
                        <xsl:value-of select="descendant::w:t"/>OOGA BOOGA!
                    </w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:customXml>
        </w:p>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is it due to you matching the w:val of "msgnum" when the value in the input XML is Dxmsgnum?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that -- one of my attempts was to match on the `@w:element` and I must not have changed it. But changing it also fails to produce the correct result. It's really strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead? Copies over nodes normally, except inserts your desired child in empty w:pPr elements that are children of a w:p element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >

    <!-- Identity Transform -->

    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() "/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="w:pPr[parent::w:p//@* = 'msgnum']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <w:pStyle w:val="ActionRequired" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit: Could you clarify what counts as an acceptable check? Any element containing an attribute equals to "msgnum"? I fixed the template match to reflect this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I had thought of this as well, but testing for some iteration of `msgnum` is required. Otherwise, there are lots of instances of character-level formatting this will catch.

Comment: I edited it to perform a check against any attribute having that value, but you may have to be more specific if you want something else.

Comment: Oh, boy. Thank you so much. Also, I feel extremely stupid right now. My transformation scenario (I use Oxygen) was pointing to the wrong version of the stylesheet. All of the templates above, including yours, work correctly. Sheesh. I'm really sorry.

Comment: I just realized that I had misread something you wrote... If you end up using something like what I wrote, don't include the "count" test. I had included that because I thought you said to update a non-empty pPr element, but you had said to add a non-empty child. Updated again to reflect that.